# -ed suffix in compounds

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semantics, suffixes, compounds, morphology

I read somewhere in a book on morphology that -ed suffix in compounds conveys the notion of having something, therefore "a one-armed man" means " a man having one arm", so i was wandering whether the same can be applied for "a good-beginninged story" to mean "a story having a good beginning".

Comment: No, that doesn't work. You get _soft-shelled crab_ and _bespectacled head_, but that _-ed_ suffix doesn't apply to very  many nouns.

Comment: Could you please explain the question a little more?  have you found the compound 'good-beginning' in any dictionary you have checked?  If not, you are asking whether you can make up a compound and then use it to form an 'adjective' ending in -ed.  However that may be, do you think the 'word' "good-beginninged" sits comfortably in your mouth as you say it?  Is it better, for example, than 'well-begun' or well-started'?

Comment: Without any doubt, it is better to use those that you mentioned but i was thinking whether it can convey that particular meaning.